# meaning of warning and type in ML

Tags: sml

```
fun a(list) = 
   let
   val num = length(hd(list))
   fun inner(list) = 
      if num = length(hd(list)) then
         if tl(list) = nil then true
         else inner(tl(list))
      else false
   in
   if length(hd(list))-1 = length(tl(list)) then inner(tl(list))
   else false
   end;
```

this is ml code and I got this warning and type.

```
stdIn:6.16 Warning: calling polyEqual
val a = fn : ''a list list -> bool
```

I don't understand about the warning. why it appear and the type. ''a why it has two '? ''?
what is the difference between 'a list list and ''a list list?

Comment: You could make that function much shorter/cleaner by using pattern matching for getting the head/tail of the list. `fun a (x::xs as list) = ...`. (Note, you need a case for the empty list, too. Your current function wouldn't work on empty lists, either, but the compiler cannot discover that if you don't use pattern matching.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your second question,

> why it has two '? ''? what is the difference between 'a list list and
>   ''a list list?

`''a` is the same as `'a`, but requires it to be an *equality type*. An *equality type* in SML is a type that can be compared using `=`. Non-equality types cannot be compared using `=`. When you create a datatype, you can specify whether it is an equality type or not.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Then is it possible to change the type '''a' to ''a' with my code? Also I don't want to have the warning sign there. Do you have any hint or suggestion for that?

Comment: @Q123: The reason an equality type is inferred here is that you have `tl(list) = nil`, which is only allowed if the list has an equality type. You can eliminate that test by using pattern-matching; change `if tl(list) = nil then true else inner(tl(list))` to `case tl list of nil => true | _ => false`. Or, for that matter, you can use the predefined `null` function, which returns `true` if its argument is the empty list: this whole sub-expression is equivalent to `null (tl list)`.

Answer (score 5):

Excerpted from [ML Hints](http://www.cs.williams.edu/~freund/cs334/auxread/ML-hints.html):

> `Warning: calling polyEqual` [may occur] whenever you use `=` to
>   compare two values with polymorphic type.
>
> For example, `fun eq(x,y) = (x = y);` will cause this warning to be
>   generated, because `x` and `y` will have polymorphic type `''a`. This
>   is perfectly fine and you may ignore the warning. It is not reporting
>   any kind of semantic error or type error in your code. The compiler
>   reports the warning because there can be a slight ineffeciency in how
>   ML tests whether two values of a polymorphic type are equal. In
>   particular, to perform the equality test, the run-time system must
>   first determine what types of values you are currently using and then
>   determine whether the values are equal. The first part (checking the
>   run-time types) can make the `=` test slightly slower than if the
>   types are known ahead of time (such as when we test `3 = 4` and know
>   that the `=` test is being applied to integers). However, that is not
>   something most users of ML ever need to worry about...

Comment: - please do not create tag wikis that simply have a hyperlink; these entries are not helpful, and will be rejected as such.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/665815#./665815?&_suid=13479831077180370411440197149

Answer (score 1):

```
dict=val a =[("a",[1,2]),("b",[2,3])] ;
```

here is the code which has implementation of look up in dictionary

```
 fun look key [] = []
| look key ((a,b)::xs) = if (key =a ) then b else look key xs ;
```

which gives output as

```
 test1.sml:8.36 Warning: calling polyEqual
```

It is because it does not know what are the types which are compared so
the below code says that both are string type .

```
fun look (key:string) [] = []
| look (key:string) ((a:string,b)::xs) = if (key =a ) then b else look (key:string) xs ;
```