# how to find number of occurrences in ML string list?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

I am new to ML, here is my attemp to writing a function that receives:

- list of strings L
- string str
- int counter

the function should return the number of occurrences of `str` in `L`

*Here is my code:*

```
(* 
 * return number of occurences of str in L
 * count should be initialized to zero. 
 *)
 fun aux_num_of_occur(L: string list) (str:string) (count:int) =
    if null L then 0
    else if str = hd(L) then
        aux_num_of_occur tl(L) str (count+1)
    else
        aux_num_of_occur tl(L) str count
```

Those are the errors i got:

```
Error: case object and rules don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  rule domain: string list * string * int
  object: ('Z list -> 'Z list) * 'Y * 'X
  in expression:
    (case (arg,arg,arg)
      of (L : string list,str : string,count : int) =>
           if null L
           then 0
           else if <exp> = <exp> then <exp> <exp> else <exp> <exp>)

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

**My Questions:**

1. What is wrong with the syntax?
2. it is not clear to me what the error message says: what is a
   `rule` and an `object` in this case?
3. how can i return a `int` by recursively calling a function? is it by passing to it a `counter` as an argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a classical mistake: `tl(L)` and `tl L` are the same thing -- you don't need parentheses for function application in ML-like languages, you just juxtapose the function and the argument(s).

So `aux_num_of_occur tl(L) ...` is the same thing as `aux_num_of_occur tl L ...`, i.e. you are trying to apply `aux_num_of_occur` to the `tl` function, not to a list of strings. Now, the `tl` function has type `'a list -> 'a list` and that is what you see in the error message (with `'a` being `'Z` there).

I ought to say that this style with those `null`, `hd`, and `tl` functions is not very idiomatic in SML -- you could use pattern-mathing instead. It is also more convenient to make `aux_num_of_occur` local to prevent namespace pollution, prevent incorrect usage (you control the initial value of `count`). Additionally, this gives you the advantage of not passing `str` all the time when recursing further.

```
fun num_of_occur ss str =
  let
      fun loop [] count = count
        | loop (s::ss) count =
            if s = str
            then loop ss (count + 1)
            else loop ss count
  in
      loop ss 0
  end
```

Notice that `num_of_occur` has a more general type `''a list -> ''a -> int`, where `''a` means any type with equality comparison. The compiler will generate a warning

> Warning: calling polyEqual

which you can either ignore or add some type annotations to `num_of_occur`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444381/2747511) for more detail.

Comment: Also, here is how it would look like with a fold: `fun num_of_occur ss str = foldl (fn (s, count) => if s = str then count + 1 else count) 0 ss`

Comment: @SimonShine Or, if I were to be fancy (and to illustrate that `if` is an expression): `fun num_of_occur ss str =
  foldl (fn (s, count) => count + (if s = str then 1 else 0)) 0 ss`

Comment: @SimonShine I think this belongs as it's own answer! Someone looking up this question should be be able to see to the concise, idiomatic hi-order solution as well as the explicit recursive one (but, please, name your helper function for clarity's sake!) :).